# Can't comment on YouTube videos in Chromium

Tags: chromium, youtube

I can't comment or like comments on YouTube videos like shown here: [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3kysxnhndc)

This only happens in Chromium and not Firefox or Google Chrome. I am running *Ubuntu 14.04 64bit* and *Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972)* of Chromium.

Could someone help me to get this working in Chromium?

**Reply to Krowe**

I know, but I don't think this is the reason for this. I took a screenshot with Chromium and Google Chrome running side by side and by the look of it, it looks like I have logged in exactly the same way in both.
[image: http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202014-07-06%2023:28:46.png]

And as we can see in Chromium my profile image doesn't show on the comment section, but does in Google Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It has to do with blocked cookies**

In Chromium, click on the weird C with an X on it.
[image]

then click on the show cookies and other site data, it will bring up this window.
[image]

click on the blocked tab and then click on each item and allow it(mine had about 5) They will still be there, but when you hit close, it will ask you to reload to apply new cookie settings, and presto, you can now comment, I went to the icon again afterwards and repeated this just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You should report this bug at chromium issue, let know the developer (even Google developer) about this problem, and they will fix it. 
[Open Issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry)

Comment: I' not good at filing bugs, but I reported it here: http://bit.ly/ChromiumBug

Comment: It vary good! you can add the images that you post here at the bug report (at the comments). They will ask you for more information if they need. I hope they solve your problem. if you like my answer, you can support it by click it for the answer, and give it +1.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has recently attempted to force users into using Google+ accounts for everything on YouTube. At first they just didn't let you comment on post made by other Google+ users but now you cannot post new comments unless you use Google+. I'd guess that you've logged into a Google+ account in Firefox but not in your other browsers. I've been trying to get it to work without verifying my identity for awhile. The best solution I have found is to set your account up like a business. As unlikely as it may sound, it is time to start looking for other places to put your videos if this matters to you as it should.

Comment: I updated question with image showing Google Chrome and Chromium side by side

Comment: Have you tried logging out and in again plus deleting cache and cookies. I have encountered the same problem and it was always some logging in issue, which got resolved after doing the above mentioned things.